# Rails can't write to serialized array field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the array on my model and set up, and when I go to write the array onto my record it says COMMIT true, yet checking the field on that record immediately after returns an empty array.

Model:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :content, Array
  attr_accessible :content
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddContentToFeatures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :features, :content, :text, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

What I tried, along with various symbol and string syntaxes, is this:

```
> f=Feature.new
> f.content_will_change! #i feel like i shouldn't have to do this
> f.content = ['sadasd','asdasd']
> f.save!
    BEGIN
    COMMIT
=> true
> f.content
=> []
```

How do I persist the array on the model?

Comment: I serialize arrays all the time without problems, but the database just assumes a text field, nothing more. I'd `rake db:rollback` and then remove the `array: true, default: []` and then migrate again.  @peterkim 's suggestion makes sense to me.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn But PostgreSQL understands SQL arrays so using the `serialize` kludge with PostgreSQL is a bit nasty.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `postgresql` tag.  Either answer works, but the answer by @muistooshort is best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using native PostgreSQL arrays (which you are since you have `array: true` in your migration) then you shouldn't use `serialize` at all. [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) is used to store YAML in the database:

> **serialize**(attr_name, class_name_or_coder = Object)
>
> If you have an attribute that needs to be saved to the database as an object, and retrieved as the same object, then specify the name of that attribute using this method and it will be handled automatically. The serialization is done through YAML. If `class_name` is specified, the serialized object must be of that class on assignment and retrieval. Otherwise `SerializationTypeMismatch` will be raised.

So `serialize` simply stores a YAML-encoded object inside a `text` column in the database. But PostgreSQL, ActiveRecord in Rails4, and the underlying PostgreSQL driver all understands arrays without all the YAML unpleasantness.

Leave the `array: true` in your migration, remove the `serialize :content, Array` from your model, and it should work fine. As an added bonus, you'll be able to use all of [PostgreSQL's array operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) to query your `content`, `serialize` doesn't allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The default data structure for Rails' serializer is a Hash which you are not saving into `f.content`.

To save an Array to the serialized content, try in your Feature Model the following:

```
serialize :content, Array
```

Comment: hi. I've done it with the array specified as here, as well. I only removed it because it didn't seem to be doing anything. I'm getting the same results whether or not Array is specified. Added to the question tho.

Comment: You may want to try to update that migration without the `array: true, default: []`

Comment: yes, that was it, thanks. I wonder why that's in the rails docs... I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: sorry, had to give it to muisshort for the added bonuses doing it that way.